# Fastest way to get the RGB average inside of a non-rectangular contour in the CMSampleBuffer

Tags: ios, swift, vision, cifilter

I am trying to get the RGB average inside of a non-rectangular multi-edge (closed) contour generated over a face landmark region in the frame (think of it as a face contour) from AVCaptureVideoDataOutput. I currently have the following code,

```
        let landmarkPath = CGMutablePath()
        let landmarkPathPoints = landmark.normalizedPoints
            .map({ landmarkPoint in
                CGPoint(
                    x: landmarkPoint.y * faceBoundingBox.height + faceBoundingBox.origin.x,
                    y: landmarkPoint.x * faceBoundingBox.width + faceBoundingBox.origin.y)
            })
        landmarkPath.addLines(between: landmarkPathPoints)
        landmarkPath.closeSubpath()

        let averageFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIAreaAverage", parameters: [kCIInputImageKey: frame, kCIInputExtentKey: landmarkPath])!
        let outputImage = averageFilter.outputImage!
```

However, it currently throws *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFType CGRectValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x283a57a80' terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException. I suspect this is as the kCIInputExtentKey is not a proper CIVector rectangular object. Is there anyway to fix this? How can I define a non-rectangular region for the CIAreaAverage filter? If not possible, what's the most efficient way of getting the average RGB across the region of interest?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Hmm, that's difficult. You, unfortunately, can't pass arbitrary shapes to `CIAreaAverage`. The `extent` always needs to be a rectangle (with origin and size). I imagine you could mask the image with your path first, but then you need to be careful not to count transparent pixels into your average. Maybe you could use a histogram for that somehow...

Comment: I see, thanks for your response! Are there any alternatives to CIAverageArea that would allow non-rectangular regions? I have seen examples for face-manipulation apps so I would suspect that if one can apply a colour filter to just the nose, it should also be possible to average RGB values across that area, right?

Comment: I'm not aware of any built-in filters that take arbitrary shapes as input. I guess masking would be the way to go here. Also, consider using blur filters to average pixels in an area instead of calculating _the_ average pixel value.

Comment: I see. I'll take a swing at it. Do you if one could use ARKit alternatively to get average RGB for various regions across the face? Thanks a lot for your help btw!

Comment: Well, you could probably access the actual `capturedImage` of the `ARFrame` and combine it with the face tracking information to create a masked image. Then use Core Image to calculate the average of that image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you could make all pixels outside of the contour transparent then you could use `CIKmeans` filter with `inputCount` equal `1` and the `inputExtent` set to the extent of the frame to get the average color of the area inside the contour (the output of the filter will contain 1-pixel image and the color of the pixel is what you are looking for).

Now, to make all pixels transparent outside of the contour, you could do something like this:

1. Create a mask image but setting all pixels inside the contour white and black outside (set background to black and fill the path with white).
2. Use `CIBlendWithMask` filter where:

   - `inputBackgroundImage` is a fully transparent (clear) image
   - `inputImage` is the original frame
   - `inputMaskImage` is the mask you created above

The output of that filter will give you the image with all pixels outside the contour fully transparent. And now you can use the `CIKMeans` filter with it as described at the beginning.

BTW, if you want to play with every single of the 230 filters out there check this app out: https://apps.apple.com/us/app/filter-magic/id1594986951

### UPDATE:

CIFilters can only work with CIImages. So the mask image has to be a CIImage as well.
One way to do that is to create a CGImage from CAShapeLayer containing the mask and then create CIImage out of it. Here is how the code could look like:

```
// Create the closed contour path from points
let path = CGMutablePath()
path.addLines(between: points)
path.closeSubpath()

// Create CAShapeLayer matching the dimensions of the input frame
let layer = CAShapeLayer()
layer.frame = frame.extent // Assuming frame is the input CIImage with the face

// Set background and fill color and set the path
layer.fillColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
layer.path = path

// Render the contents of the CAShapeLayer to CGImage
let width = Int(layer.bounds.width)
let height = Int(layer.bounds.height)
let context = CGContext(data: nil,
                        width: width,
                        height: height,
                        bitsPerComponent: 8,
                        bytesPerRow: 4 * width,
                        space: CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(),
                        bitmapInfo: CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedLast.rawValue)!

layer.render(in: context)
let cgImage = context.makeImage()!

// Create CIImage out of it
let ciImage = CIImage(cgImage: cgImage)

// To create clear background CIImage just do this:
let bgImage = CIImage.clear.cropped(to: frame.extent)
```

Comment: Should I generate a UIImage or are there better options for the image mask?

Comment: @P.B.Please see my updated answer

Comment: Amazing! Thanks soo much!